# C++ Writing a vector of objects to file

Tags: c++, object, vector, ofstream, writetofile

I have a vector of objects with quite a few variables (name, type, length etc) which I am trying to write to file.

```
vector <Boat> berths;

void Boat::write_boats()
{
    ofstream file("records_file.txt");
    for (Boat b : berths)
    {
        file << owner_name << "; " << boat_name << "; " << type << "; " << length << "; " << draft << '\n';
    }

    file.close();
}


void save_records()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < berths.size(); i++)
    {
        berths[i].write_boats();
    }
}
```

I call the save_records() function with a menu option that ends the application.

The output i get is:

1) If i register a boat object, close the app and go in the text file, I can see the object written twice.

2) If i register 2 objects and I go in the text file, only the last (second) object has been written to file, and it shows 3 times.

Now my questions are:

What causes the double output?

Why is only the last object written to file? I thought the loop would fix that but it didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I can spot: "i = 1" in the loop should be "i = 0", because array indexes start from 0. The second: you iterate 'berths' array, so you will get N * N boats saved, if you have N boats in 'berths'.

The simple solution would be

```
void save_all()
{
     ofstream file("records_file.txt");
     for (Boat b : berths)
     {
         file << b.owner_name << "; " << b.boat_name << "; " << b.type << "; " << b.length << "; " << b.draft << '\n';
     }
}
```

If you have to make 'owner_name', 'type' and the rest of the fields as private, then you would have to declare

```
void Boat::save(std::ofstream& f) const
{
    file << owner_name << "; " << boat_name << "; " << type << "; " << length << "; " << draft << '\n';
}
```

and modify 'save_all' to

```
void save_all()
{
    ofstream file("records_file.txt");
    for (const Boat& b: berths)
        b.save(f);
}
```

Comment: The i=1 is intentional, as I am storing the boats starting with 1 (the reason is not relevant to the problem in question  though) 

Anyways, I tried  doing it the way you suggested, and it now outputs some gibberish (; ; ; -858993460; -858993460) and then the object...

Comment: Okay, I tried again with the const and everything, and now it at least saves every different object, but the first output is still the gibberish I was talking about.

I realise it might in fact have to do with the 0 index that I am not using, now that i think about it haha. I ll see if I can get rid of it :) Thank you for the help

Comment: Glad it all helped.

Answer (score 0):

Every time `ofstream file("records_file.txt");` is called, it created a new file and overwrite it, if you want to append in the file you have to open it by this way:

```
ofstream file("records_file.txt", ios::app);
```

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Thank you, i moved it to the save_records() function, which is only called once right before closing the application :)

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are using something like while(!bla.eof()), if so then it reaches the end of the buffer but it needs to go past it to raise the flag, so you have the same output twice at the end.